# Make a chart from database MySQL in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, json

I want to make a chart in Android based on the data I got from my database MySQL using JSON code, here's my code :

```
package android.bloodglucose.doctor;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.SeriesSelection;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.tools.PanListener;
import org.achartengine.tools.ZoomEvent;
import org.achartengine.tools.ZoomListener;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.bloodglucose.doctor.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChartBuilder extends Activity {
  public static final String TYPE = "type";

  private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

  private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

  private XYSeries mCurrentSeries;

  private XYSeriesRenderer mCurrentRenderer;

  private String mDateFormat;

  private GraphicalView mChartView;

  private String textResult;

  private ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
  private ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();


  //private Button sendImage;

  InputStream is;

  String imageFilePath;

  private int index=1;

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);    
    mDataset = (XYMultipleSeriesDataset) savedState.getSerializable("dataset");
    mRenderer = (XYMultipleSeriesRenderer) savedState.getSerializable("renderer");
    mCurrentSeries = (XYSeries) savedState.getSerializable("current_series");
    mCurrentRenderer = (XYSeriesRenderer) savedState.getSerializable("current_renderer");
    mDateFormat = savedState.getString("date_format");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("dataset", mDataset);
    outState.putSerializable("renderer", mRenderer);
    outState.putSerializable("current_series", mCurrentSeries);
    outState.putSerializable("current_renderer", mCurrentRenderer);
    outState.putString("date_format", mDateFormat);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xy_chart);
    Button save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveChart);

    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    //mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    //mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(10);

        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Blood Sugar Increment (mg/dl)");
        mDataset.addSeries(series);
        mCurrentSeries = series;
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        mCurrentRenderer = renderer;



       cek();
             }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mChartView == null) {
      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
      mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer);
      mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
      mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
      mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
          double[] xy = mChartView.toRealPoint(0);
          if (seriesSelection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(ChartBuilder.this, "No chart element was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                ChartBuilder.this,
                "Your blood glucose level at this point is = " + (float) xy[1] + "mg/dl, where the normal level of blood glucose is < 140 mg/dl, " + textResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      });
      mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
          if (seriesSelection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(ChartBuilder.this, "No chart element was long pressed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return false; // no chart element was long pressed, so let something
            // else handle the event
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(ChartBuilder.this, "Chart element in series index "
                + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex() + " data point index "
                + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return true; // the element was long pressed - the event has been
            // handled
          }
        }
      });
      mChartView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {
        public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent e) {
          String type = "out";
          if (e.isZoomIn()) {
            type = "in";
          }
          System.out.println("Zoom " + type + " rate " + e.getZoomRate());
        }

        public void zoomReset() {
          System.out.println("Reset");
        }
      }, true, true);
      mChartView.addPanListener(new PanListener() {
        public void panApplied() {
          System.out.println("New X range=[" + mRenderer.getXAxisMin() + ", " + mRenderer.getXAxisMax()
              + "], Y range=[" + mRenderer.getYAxisMax() + ", " + mRenderer.getYAxisMax() + "]");
        }
      });
      layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    } else {
      mChartView.repaint();
    }
  }



  public void cek(){

      String url_select = "http://10.0.2.2/BloodGlucose/selectUserChart.php";

      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

      //parameter
      String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("uname");
      ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
      try {
         //add parameter
          httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

        HttpResponse httpRespose = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespose.getEntity();

        //read content
        InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String content = "";
        String line = "";

        while((line = read.readLine())!=null){
           content += line;
        }

        Log.d("ADBUG", "content: "+content);


        //json
        if(!content.equals("null")){

           try {
              JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(content);
              for(int i=0;i<jArr.length();i++){
                 JSONObject jObj = jArr.getJSONObject(i);

                 String a = jObj.getString("_id");
                 String b = jObj.getString("result");


                 ids.add(a.toString());
                 result.add(b.toString());


                 Double x,y;

                         x = Double.parseDouble(a.toString());
                         y = Double.parseDouble(b.toString());
                         mCurrentSeries.add(x, y);


              }

           } catch (JSONException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }else{
           Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }

}
```

The problem is, the chart is empty, anyone can help me?

```
my databases
_id | result|
 1  | 180   |
 2  | 200   |
 3  | 145   |
```

This is my php code : selectUserChart.php

```
<?php
   include_once("koneksi.php");   

   $username = $_REQUEST['username']; 

   $sqlString = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username_user = '$username'";

   $rs = mysql_query($sqlString);

   if($rs){
      while($objRs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
         $output[] = $objRs;
      }

      echo json_encode($output);
   }
   mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I saw in this code was related to your web service that returns the data. I commented that out as I cannot access it and added hardcoded data and the chart is displaying fine.

To see it yourself, please add the method below and call it instead of calling `cek()`.

```
private void addData() {
  mCurrentSeries.add(0, 1);
  mCurrentSeries.add(1, 2);
  mCurrentSeries.add(2, 1);
  mCurrentSeries.add(3, 2);
}
```

Comment: well, I've tried change mCurrentSeries.add(x, y); to mCurrentSeries.add(100, 100); , if the problem related to web service, if i change x,y with number it should shown rigt? but it still didn't show on the chart :(

Comment: Add a new line: mCurrentSeries.add(150, 150); such as you have 2 points on the chart.

Comment: I've been adding another points, but it still didn't show on the chart, but when I move the mCurrentSeries.add(100, 100) in @Override 
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
} it show, i wonder what's the problem

Comment: thank you, it worked, but i want to get the data from my database, I've edited my question above(add the php code), can you show me how? thank you very much

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question for the php guys. I'm not one of them.